# Assigning local storage from variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, local-storage

I've just started programming with JavaScript and have come to a little problem. I am trying to place information into local storage. The key is taken from a variable, as is the value.

Here is my code, It might not make very much sense.
Note: **Pies** is just an example.

```
<form name="buy">
<input id="Quantity" name="Quantity" type="number" max="2" min="1" value="1">
<input type="submit" id="confirm" onclick="confirm()">
</form>

<p id="Output">

<script>
function confirm()
 var name = "Pies";
 var quantity = document.getElementsById("Quantity");

 if (localStorage["number"] == null) {
    var number = "1";
}
 else {
  // Put the name into a text box.
  number = number += 1;
}
  document.getElementById("Output") = localStorage[number];
  alert("You Stored: " + localStorage[number]);
}
```

The if/else statement is supposed to detect whether the the item **"Number"** exists yet in the local storage, and if not creates it.

Then, the value of **number** in local storage is assigned from the HTML form. **Number** is simply the key of the local storage item, whilst its value is **quantity**, taken from the form.

Sorry if my script doesn't make any sense, I'm new to the area of JavaScript.
Any help would be greatly appreciated,
-Luke

Comment: you are not doing anything with the value in quantity in the code. Your description and code doesn't match. Explain the logic properly

Comment: Very good point, @mithunsatheesh. I will look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var quantity = document.getElementById("Quantity");` instead `var quantity = document.getElementsById("Quantity");`

variable is not inside quotes or double quotes, you cann't sum string.
`if (localStorage[number] == null) {
    var number = 1;
}`

You've not stored data, use `localStorage.setItem(yourItem)`

and get data using `localStorage.getItem(yourItem)`

`yourItem` is a string or a number, if you want your user set it from textarea set the value as `var yourItem = document.getElementById("Quantity").value;`

**You need to learn javascript much more**

Comment: Oh yeah, Thanks for pointing that out. I completely forgot to localStorage.setItem. Thanks for your help!